# Determining the decay constant for a damped wave

Tags: waves, string

My question is short and simple. If a damped, travelling wave (say on a string) could be described as

$y\left( x,t\right) =Ae^{-\gamma x}\sin \left( kx-\omega t\right)$

how could/would one determine the decay/dampening constant $\gamma$ mathematically?

Comment: Please clarify:  do you mean how would you find the value of $\gamma$ experimentally?  Or perhaps you mean to ask what value to use in a theoretical description?  Some context would help.

Comment: You mean experimentally? You could look at the envelope of the motion, i.e. plot the max. and min. amplitude for every point along x. The sin term can only take values between -1 and 1, so the envelope of the wave is the exponential term.

Comment: Mathematically? Determine from what? What's your input?

Comment: What other information about the system is available?  How you derive something depends on what you're deriving it from.

Comment: I want to know what realistic factors would determine the parameter $\gamma$ and how to describe the constant when considering them. Of course it could be found experimentally.

Comment: @J.D'Alembert: Unless you tell us your model of reality, we can't tell you what's "realistic". There is absolutely nothing "realistic" about a mathematical function. It's nothing but an ideal of man that doesn't have any meaning outside of itself unless there is a prescription of how to map its mathematical meaning to some physical meaning. That's called an "ontology" and your question lacks that.

Comment: The problem is it's not a specific model. Let's say the wave is formed by oscillating one end of a string endlessly from the max/min values of the Amplitude. $A$ is the Amplitude before the "decay." Obviously energy is being taken from the system but I want to know how could I determine the decay constant if I knew the factors that determined it, e.g. heat loss. For instance, if tension and heat loss contributed to the loss of energy from the system, how would I weigh up these factors when determine $\gamma$?

Comment: I would appreciate an example of a model and how the factors of energy loss were used in determining $\gamma$

Comment: @J.D'Alembert: Such a function is the result of a wave equation with a linear damping term, which can be the model for any number of physical scenarios. You are basically turning in circles, because in each case the damping is determined trough a different physical mechanism. The solution you are presenting has absolutely nothing to do with that mechanism or even the reasons of the person who simplified that actual mechanism to a linear damping term, which could be practical or merely for teaching purposes (because the real physics is too hard).

Comment: @CuriousOne I don't quite understanding what you mean. Are you just suggesting the aforementioned equation is too general and/or can't be used to find $\gamma$?

Comment: @J.D'Alembert: Yes, that is exactly what I am suggesting. If you can tell us what interests you, in detail, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string moving in a fluid in which the damping force $F$ is proportional to the transverse velocity of the wave $v$, then you can compute the damping per wavelength that will occur - and from this you can derive the factor $\gamma$ that you are asking about.

A very deep treatment can be found at http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/waves/transverse.pdf